# jquery How to make a div auto move, when (.a input) width increase?

Tags: jquery

I did (.a input) auto increase width, when user type.
But now i don't know how to make (.b) at same time  auto move to right? avoid overlapping
Thank you in advance.

```
if ($a.width()"+1px"){
 $b.animate({
  left: "+1px"
 }, 1000 );
};
```

html css

```
<input class="a" value="texttext">
<input class="b" value="texttext">

.a{
position: absolute;
left: 10px;
top: 22px;
width: 100px;
font-size: 19px;
}
.b{
position: absolute;
left: 110px;
top: 22px;
width: 100px;
font-size: 19px;
}
```

Comment: `($a.width()"+1px")` won't work because for 1 you're adding a string now a number, and 2 anything that isn't 0 will be true, plus there is no loop checking this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a different approach to this problem. You need to hook to the `keyup` event of `input.a` and get the text width as you're typing the text. However, you cannot get the width of the text by normal means so you would need to employ some sort of cloned div to be updated with `input.a`'s text every time you type:

```
$('#aclone').html($('input.a').val());

$('input.a').keyup(function () {

    var clone_width, apos, bleft;

    // make clone contain what input.a contains
    $('#aclone').html($(this).val());

    // get the width of cloned text
    clone_width = $('#aclone').width();

    // if it's bigger than input.a's current size, resize it
    if (clone_width > $(this).width()) {
        $(this).width(clone_width);
    }

    // calculate position for b
    apos = $(this).position();
    bleft = apos['left'] + $(this).width();

    // adjust input.b's position
    $('input.b').css({'left': bleft});

});
```

> Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/aemhd/

*P.S.: my fiddle has the clone div shown. If you want to hide it, do not use `display:none` as the browser wouldn't able to calculate it's width if it's hidden, instead just position it outside of the viewport using `top:-9999px;left:-9999px;` in CSS.*